# Using svn with Textmate

Tags: svn, textmate

Coming from IDEs with full-blown svn support such as Eclipse and Netbeans, I'm wondering what is the recommended way to use svn with Textmate? Is it all manual, ie using the command line, or are there features that allow you to diff/checkin/merge/etc in Textmate itself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a plugin for textmate wich can be found here: http://www.reinventar.com/2008/07/svn-plugin-for-textmate/

The plugin mentioned in that post is SVNMate

Comment: Note that SVNMate "only" displays the svn status as badges in the project tree and is no longer developed. It's superseded by ProjectPlus (http://ciaranwal.sh/projectplus) of the same developer. Execution of svn commands can be already done via the built-in Subversion bundle (ctrl+shift+a).

Answer (score 7):

Ciarán Walsh has replaced SVNMate with [ProjectPlus](http://ciaranwal.sh/projectplus) -- in addition to Subverison it handles Git, Mercurial, Bazaar and Svk.

Comment: Version 1.54a for OS X 10.6+, TextMate 1.5.10 (April 2012): https://github.com/fdintino/projectplus

Answer (score 3):

I've never actually used it, but isn't there an existing [Subversion bundle](http://manual.macromates.com/en/bundles#subversion) in TextMate.  Is that not adequate for you?

Comment: Thanks, I found that and it works great, however it does not show the status of changed files so SVNMate seems to take care of that.

Answer (score 2):

The svn menus can be accessed through ctrl-shift-a. I find that this bundle is a bit less intuitive than using svn in eclipse, but it does do the job. The one gotcha that I've gotten caught on is that you need at least one open file in the project in order for the svn menu options to be available. I close my tabs as soon as I'm done with the files, so this has come up a few times.

Answer (score 0):

Although Project Plus is great for quick visual checks on file status, you will still probably need the SVN bundle for doing diffs and merges - which I have to say the existing SVN bundle handles pretty well.

Try looking at the merge options; you can do a side by side comparison of diffs, choosing what you want to include in the merge from either file.

What you can't do is do diffs on arbitrary files - however you can do this using the diff bundle, funnily enough. It's not something that I need to do as regularly, but it has come in handy a few times.

Answer (score 0):

project plus is the textmate way of doing versioning ;)